# URLRewriting challenge

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I'm using URLRewritingNet 2.0.  How do I rewrite URL's in ASP.NET?

Here is the request:

- Input: `www.sampleweb.com/param1/value1/param2/value2/default.aspx`
- Output: `www.sampleweb.com/default.aspx?param1=value1&param2=value2`

It must work dynamically like this `param1/value1/param2/value2/ ... /paramN/valueN`

Comment: That's indeed a bad way to pass parameters!

Comment: What If your Input is Like: www.sampleweb.com/value1/value2/default.aspx and output could be what you are looking, if it is OK then I will provide you link and help to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good way to pass key/value pairs.

You should assume the key based on the values position.  That makes life a lot easier.  HttpContext.RewritePath (with its variations) is how you go about transforming the url.

Answer (score 0):

So...basically you can't do this in the "rewrite" node in your web.config file using ASP.Net's URL Rewriter.

But you could do it elsewhere in your code (an HTTP Module, or Begin Request, or whatever).  To transform you URL's you could do something like this:

```
  string strRegex= @"/([^/]*)/([^/]*)";
  RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
  Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
  string strTargetString = @"/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3/param4/value4";
  string strReplace = @"$1=$2&";
```

If you combine that with matching the filename (here's the RE):

```
  (.*)/([^/]*\..*)$
```

And then re-composing the complete URL--then you could Server.Execute or whatever (if on your own server) or otherwise proxy over to where you want this processed. Yup, it's a little ugly, but if you don't have control of the shape of the request coming at you, this is a way to transform it.